# WCF method returning JSON / XML objects not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I was new to WCF, i was trying to build a sample application using VS 2010 and code provided below

IProductService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProductService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    Products SelectAllProducts();
}
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
[CollectionDataContract]
public class Products : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Product>
{
}
```

ProductService.cs

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    public Products SelectAllProducts()
    {
        var products = new Products();
        var prod = new Product();

        prod.ProductId = 1;
        prod.Name = "SAMSUNG";
        products.Add(prod);

        prod = new Product();
        prod.ProductId = 2;
        prod.Name = "RELIANCE";
        products.Add(prod);

        return products;
    }
}
```

http://localhost:1050/WCFService1/ProductService.svc/SelectAllProducts

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and if try using the above url blank is getting displayed can some one help me ???
thanks in advance ..

Comment: What's your WCF service configuration ?
Maybe you need to add Products to ServiceKnownTypes.

Comment: fun part is you have added your localhost link here, send your production url

Comment: @DmitriyReznik ill update the web.config

Comment: @manny i was trying that on my localhost if this works ill make use of production url ...

Comment: Try setting the KnownType attribute to your datacontract classes. Here's url for reference: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560218/wcf-configuring-known-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the service binding the web.config. Try adding line such as below:

```
<services>
     <service name="[Your Namespace].ProductService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="[Your Namespace].IProductService" />
     </service>
</services>
```

Its important that you use `webHttpBinding` for REST WCF Services. Also you need to attach `webHttpBehavior` - that's possible by using [WebServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webservicehostfactory.aspx) in your svc file. For example,

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="[YourNameSpace].ProductService" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

See below for more info:

http://saravananarumugam.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/simple-rest-implementation-with-webhttpbinding/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do some change in interface

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "JsonpAjaxService")]    
interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    method() 

}
```

add some code on class like below

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService
```

your web.config file like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>  
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <authentication mode="None" />
  </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
 <system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webScriptEndpoint>
       <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
    </webScriptEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```